# can anyone find the error in the function calling in my python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, streamlit

here i have defined a db_embedding function i want to call and create vector embedding and store it into the pinecone vector data base problem is not call my function properly can anyone find the where is the error coming in my code
here split_docs_data contains my chunks of Data

```
split_docs_data = split_docs(data)
st.write("length of doc", len(split_docs_data))

# END TASK CREATING CHUNKS

# START THE VECTOR DATABASE INTEGRATION


def db_embeddings(
    docs,
    api_key="5a83b434-bbd7-4336-8b87-622eb10b0952",
    environment="gcp-starter",
    index_name="langchain-doc1-embed",
):
    embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    pinecone.init(api_key=api_key, environment=environment)

    index_name = index_name

    if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
        pinecone.create_index(
            name=index_name,
            metric="cosine",
            dimension=len(embeddings.embed_query("hello")),
        )

    Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name)
    # index = Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name)


# getting the Pinecone Api keys and enviroment to create the enviroment

try:
    if split_docs_data:
        st.text(
            "Please Provide the following Details: Pinecone API key, Index Name, and Environment of Pinecone"
        )

        api_key = st.text_input("Enter the API key")
        index_name = st.text_input("Enter the Index Name")
        environment = st.text_input("Enter the Environment")
        parameters = {
            "api_key": api_key,
            "index_name": index_name,
            "environment": environment,
        }

        # Collect the provided details and call db_embeddings with the specified parameters
        if st.button("Submit"):
            db_embeddings(
                docs=split_docs_data,
                **{key: value for key, value in parameters.items() if value},
            )
            st.write("Task Done")
        else:
            st.write("Waiting for Submit...")
    else:
        st.write("No documents to process.")

except Exception as e:
    st.write(f"Error During the Embedding: {str(e)}")
```

I want to store my vector to pinecone vector database and i called the function but this not get fine if anyone can find what the error in my code is very helpful why my function not work properly

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
here i have defined a db_embedding function i want to call and create
```

vector embedding and store it into the pinecone vector data base problem is
not call my function properly can anyone find the where is the error coming
in my code here split_docs_data contains my chunks of Data

```
split_docs_data = split_docs(data)
st.write("length of doc", len(split_docs_data))

# END TASK CREATING CHUNKS

# START THE VECTOR DATABASE INTEGRATION


def db_embeddings(
    docs,
    api_key="5a83b434-bbd7-4336-8b87-622eb10b0952",
    environment="gcp-starter",
    index_name="langchain-doc1-embed",
):
    embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    pinecone.init(api_key=api_key, environment=environment)

    index_name = index_name

    if index_name not in pinecone.list_indexes():
        pinecone.create_index(
            name=index_name,
            metric="cosine",
            dimension=len(embeddings.embed_query("hello")),
        )

    Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name)
    # index = Pinecone.from_documents(docs, embeddings, index_name=index_name)


# getting the Pinecone Api keys and enviroment to create the enviroment

try:
    if split_docs_data:
        st.text(
            "Please Provide the following Details: Pinecone API key, Index Name, and Environment of Pinecone"
        )

        api_key = st.text_input("Enter the API key")
        index_name = st.text_input("Enter the Index Name")
        environment = st.text_input("Enter the Environment")
        parameters = {
            "api_key": api_key,
            "index_name": index_name,
            "environment": environment,
        }

        # Collect the provided details and call db_embeddings with the specified parameters
        if st.button("Submit"):
            db_embeddings(
                docs=split_docs_data,
                **{key: value for key, value in parameters.items() if value},
            )
            st.write("Task Done")
        else:
            st.write("Waiting for Submit...")
    else:
        st.write("No documents to process.")

except Exception as e:
    st.write(f"Error During the Embedding: {str(e)}")


I want to store my vector to pinecone vector database and i called the 
function but this not get fine if anyone can find what the error in my code 
is very helpful why my function not work properly
```